# TypeScript type inference/narrowing challenge

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inference, narrowing

I'm currently trying to improve the types on some existing code. My code looks roughly like this:

```
/* dispatcher.ts */
interface Message {
    messageType: string;
}

class Dispatcher<M extends Message> {    
    on<
        MessageType extends M["messageType"],
        SubMessage extends M & { messageType: MessageType }
    >(
        messageType: MessageType,
        handler: (message: SubMessage) => void
    ): void { }
}

/* messages.ts */
interface AddCommentMessage {
    messageType: "ADD_COMMENT";
    commentId: number;
    comment: string;
    userId: number;
}

interface PostPictureMessage {
    messageType: "POST_PICTURE";
    pictureId: number;
    userId: number;
}

type AppMessage = AddCommentMessage | PostPictureMessage;

/* app.ts */
const dispatcher = new Dispatcher<AppMessage>();

dispatcher.on("ADD_COMMENT", (message: AddCommentMessage ) => {
                                    /* ^^ REMOVE THIS TYPE HINT!*/
    console.log(message.comment);
});
```

I'd like to remove the need to explicitly narrow the type of the message passed to the message handler (where `/*REMOVE THIS TYPE HINT!*/` is), such that it correctly narrows to the type that has a matching `messageType` type (e.g. if `messageType` is `"ADD_COMMENT"` then `message` should be `AddCommentMessage`).

If this is not possible right now please let me know. I'm under the impression that it isn't but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible, unless you are willing to change the code quite a bit.

Your base interface

```
interface Message {
    messageType: string;
}
```

is too general, I think `messageType: string` precludes any inference based on the value of the `messageType`, and looks like it's impossible to sufficiently narrow it in the `Dispatcher` interface.

If you limit the code to `AppMessage` and its descendants only, here is an example how to make typescript to infer the types you need, guided by string literal types (`keyof AppMessageMap` is actually a union of string literal types `"ADD_COMMENT" | "POST_PICTURE"`):

```
/* dispatcher.ts */

class Dispatcher {    
    on<
        MessageType extends keyof AppMessageMap
    >(
        messageType: MessageType,
        handler: (message: AppMessageMap[MessageType] & {messageType: MessageType}) => void
    ): void { }
}

/* messages.ts */
interface AddCommentMessage {
    commentId: number;
    comment: string;
    userId: number;
}

interface PostPictureMessage {
    pictureId: number;
    userId: number;
}

interface AppMessageMap {
    "ADD_COMMENT": AddCommentMessage,
    "POST_PICTURE": PostPictureMessage
}
type AppMessage = AppMessageMap[keyof AppMessageMap];

/* app.ts */
const dispatcher = new Dispatcher();


dispatcher.on("ADD_COMMENT", (message) => {
    console.log(message.comment);
});
```

I also removed `messageType` property from the interfaces to avoid duplication, I think that intersection type in `handler` parameter achieves the same effect.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, thank you so much. It always blows my mind how powerful the type system of TypeScript is. The only thing I've changed is to make `Dispatcher` generic so that `AppMessageMap` is passed as a type parameter (I use the same `Dispatcher` for multiple application within the same codebase).