# Typed events with TypeScript and EventEmitter

Tags: generics, typescript, eventemitter

I'm trying to add strongly typed events to an EventEmitter-like system using TypeScript.

Currently, we define our types like:

```
interface TypedMsg<Name, T> {
  messageType: Name;
  message: T;
}

type TypedMsgFoo = TypedMsg<'FOO', string>;
type TypedMsgBar = TypedMsg<'BAR', number>;
type EitherFooOrBar = TypedMsgFoo | TypedMsgBar;
```

I would like to define an interface like:

```
interface EventHandler<T extends TypedMsg<any, any> {
  on: (messageType: T.messageType, handler: (T.message) => void) => void;
}
```

But Typescript doesn't support extracting subtypes like `T.messageType`.  Is there another way to do this?

The end goal would be to define handlers with proper typing with just:

```
class FooBarHandler implements EventHandler<EitherFooOrBar> {
  on(messageType: EitherFooOrBar.messageType) {...}
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339294/2228559) should help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript does support extracting types of members, just the syntax is a bit unusual - it's called [indexed access type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

```
interface TypedMsg<Name, T> {
  messageType: Name;
  message: T;
}

type TypedMsgFoo = TypedMsg<'FOO', string>;
type TypedMsgBar = TypedMsg<'BAR', number>;
type EitherFooOrBar = TypedMsgFoo | TypedMsgBar;

interface EventHandler<T extends TypedMsg<{}, {}>> {
  on: (messageType: T['messageType'], handler: (m: T['message']) => void) => void;
}

class FooBarHandler implements EventHandler<EitherFooOrBar> {
    on(
        messageType: EitherFooOrBar['messageType'], 
        handler: (m: EitherFooOrBar['message']) => void
    ) {

    }
}
```

However it will soon become pretty tedious to type all these declarations with types explicitly spelled out - you will want do devise something that will allow typescript to infer types for you, for example something like  this question: [TypeScript type inference/narrowing challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913985/typescript-type-inference-narrowing-challenge)